# MongoDB crashed, how to recover?

Tags: mongodb

I installed a MongoDB on my MacBook. Today, my MacBook crashed, after hard reboot Mac, `mongod` couldn't start up:

```
$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
2016-06-16T15:35:27.118+0800 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=44355 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=L-MY-MAC.local
2016-06-16T15:35:27.118+0800 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2016-06-16T15:35:27.118+0800 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2016-06-16T15:35:27.118+0800 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx108-4 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-06-16T15:35:27.118+0800 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-06-16T15:35:27.118+0800 [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-06-16T15:35:27.120+0800 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2016-06-16T15:35:27.120+0800 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2016-06-16T15:35:27.164+0800 [initandlisten] openExisting size 16384 less than minimum file size expectation /data/db/stock.4
2016-06-16T15:35:27.164+0800 [initandlisten] Assertion failure false src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp 112
2016-06-16T15:35:27.169+0800 [initandlisten] 0x1006c014b 0x100677502 0x100668182 0x1004d4695 0x1004db516 0x1000ec387 0x1000ece0e 0x1000efdf0 0x100107d74 0x100107fc5 0x100003f4c 0x100005823 0x100005fb1 0x1000015d4 0x1
 0   mongod                              0x00000001006c014b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x0000000100677502 _ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc + 114
 2   mongod                              0x0000000100668182 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 274
 3   mongod                              0x00000001004d4695 _ZN5mongo8DataFile12openExistingEPKc + 953
 4   mongod                              0x00000001004db516 _ZN5mongo13ExtentManager4initEv + 200
 5   mongod                              0x00000001000ec387 _ZN5mongo8Database12openAllFilesEv + 45
 6   mongod                              0x00000001000ece0e _ZN5mongo8DatabaseC2EPKcRbRKSs + 958
 7   mongod                              0x00000001000efdf0 _ZN5mongo14DatabaseHolder11getOrCreateERKSsS2_Rb + 834
 8   mongod                              0x0000000100107d74 _ZN5mongo6Client7Context11_finishInitEv + 78
 9   mongod                              0x0000000100107fc5 _ZN5mongo6Client7ContextC2ERKSsS3_b + 117
 10  mongod                              0x0000000100003f4c _ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi + 2828
 11  mongod                              0x0000000100005823 _ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi + 19
 12  mongod                              0x0000000100005fb1 main + 977
 13  mongod                              0x00000001000015d4 start + 52
 14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
2016-06-16T15:35:27.169+0800 [initandlisten] warning database /data/db stock could not be opened
2016-06-16T15:35:27.169+0800 [initandlisten] DBException 0: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp:112
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp:112, terminating
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2016-06-16T15:35:27.170+0800 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.174+0800 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2016-06-16T15:35:27.174+0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2016-06-16T15:35:27.174+0800 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

What I'm sure is, when my Mac crashed, `mongod` was idle, no any read/write operation on mongo.

How can I recover this my database?

Comment: Make a copy of /data/db and run mongod with the "--repair" option. This guarantees to bring your DB into a usable state – then you will have to have a look what data is left. _"no any read/write operation on mongo"_ None you started. But mongod uses memory mapped files and has background tasks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have important information within database and you need to recover that

Try to run

**In first terminal** 
*sudo mongod --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --smallfiles*

**In second terminal get the backup in**

*sudo mongoexport --db  -c  --out .json*

after that you need to remove and reinstall mongo db and restore your database

If you need more help please do let me know 
Regards
Muhammad Adil